# Ajax.Beginform works only once

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view of notes where I'm trying to make inline edit, the save button is working great only once but it stops working after the first submission.
here is my view code :

```
<h4>Notes</h4>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var note in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.CreatedOn)</td>
            @if (ViewData["ShowNoteType"] == null || ((bool)ViewData["ShowNoteType"] == true)) 
            { 
                <td style="width:120px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.NoteType)</td>
            }

            <td class="readOnlyProperty" data-note-id=@note.NoteID>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.LoggedBy)</td>
            <td class="readOnlyProperty" data-note-id= @note.NoteID>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Text)</td>

                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new { id = note.NoteID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = "/Notes/Edit", UpdateTargetId = "noteslist", OnComplete = "OnNotesListReloaded" }, new { @role = "form", @class = "form-inline" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <td class="editableProperty" style="display:none;" data-note-id=@note.NoteID>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => note.LoggedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                     </td>
                    <td class="editableProperty" style="display:none;" data-note-id=@note.NoteID>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => note.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                     </td>

                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => note.NoteID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => note.CandidateID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => note.JobID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => note.ContactID)
                    <td class="editableProperty" style="display:none;" data-note-id=@note.NoteID>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm save-note" title="Save">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </button>
                    </td>
                }


            <td><a class="btn btn-default edit-note" data-note-id=@note.NoteID ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true" /></a></td>
            <td class="deletebutton" data-note-id=@note.NoteID>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", new { id = note.NoteID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = "/Notes/Delete", UpdateTargetId = "noteslist", OnComplete = "OnNotesListReloaded" }, new { @role = "form", @class = "form-inline" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@note.NoteID" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="CandidateID" value="@ViewData["CandidateID"]" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="JobID" value="@ViewData["JobID"]" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ContactID" value="@ViewData["ContactID"]" />

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Delete Note">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

    @section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
}
```

the save button works perfectly only once.
and I have to put the dropdownlist and the editorfor in separate `<td>` rather than putting the whole Ajax form in `<td>` so they align right when edited. when I put the whole Ajax.Beginform in `<td>` it works perfect but, it doesn't align right at all.
so can anybody help me to make the save button works and the fields align right please

and here is my jquery code:

```
var OnNotesListReloaded = function () {

    $(".edit-note").click(function (event) {

        var elem = $(this).attr("data-note-id");
        $(".edit-note[data-note-id=" + elem + "]").hide();
        $(".readOnlyProperty[data-note-id=" + elem + "]").hide();
        $(".editableProperty[data-note-id=" + elem + "]").show();
        $(".deletebutton[data-note-id=" + elem + "]").hide();

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    OnNotesListReloaded();

});
```

Comment: Hi. If your ajax call is of post type, why would you pass noteid in the second paramter of ajax.BeginForm ?

Comment: hi, please use preventDefault method in JS, its break the Server HIT

Comment: @Vijay I've tried  :
var flag = event.isDefaultPrevented();
        alert(flag);
and it returned false.

Comment: None of this could possibly work correctly. Your using a `foreach` loop which is generating massive amounts of invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and you form controls have `name` attributes which have no relationship at all to your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an other approach to do this.
Lets start from UI to action.

**Step 1:**
Create One form only out side of the "For Loop" and set the action to
"/Notes/EditDelete", don't worry we are going to create an action in next step.

**Step 2:**
Now with buttons use action in name something like this and you can also pass the id as well for which record is being edited or deleted.

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action:Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action:Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" />
```

**Step 3:**
Now create action filter

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class MultipleActionsAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Argument { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            var isValidName = false;
            var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
            var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

            if (value != null)
            {
                controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
                isValidName = true;
            }
            return isValidName;
        }
    }
```

Step 4:
Use this filter above your actions:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleActions(Name = "action", Argument = "Edit")]
public ActionResult EditDelete(int id)
{
//Your edit code here
}
[HttpPost]
[MultipleActions(Name = "action", Argument = "Delete")]
public ActionResult EditDelete(int id) // you can pass the id to edit from view 
{
//Your Delete code here
}
```